# I have jsp oage which upload form data and file upload also same time. But i got java.io.FileNotFoundException: when there isn't file upload

Tags: forms, servlets, file-upload, ejb-3.0, filenotfoundexception

```
boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

if (isMultipart) {

        System.out.println("multipart2");
        // Create a factory for disk-based file items 
        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        // Create a new file upload handler
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        try {
            // Parse the request
            List /* FileItem */ items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator iterator = items.iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) iterator.next();

           if (item.isFormField()) //your code for getting form fields

                {
                    if (item.getFieldName().equals("btn")) {

                        if (item.getString().equals("Submit")) {
                           String name = item.getFieldName();
                           String value = item.getString();
                            System.out.println("test2" + name + value);

                        }
                        if (item.getString().equals("Save as Draft")) {
                            System.out.println("hii hii2");
                            String name = item.getFieldName();
                            String value = item.getString();
                        } 
                   }
          } if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    String fileName = item.getName();
                    System.out.println("File Upload Named :  " + fileName);
                    String root = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
                    File path = new File(root + "/uploads");
                    if (!path.exists()) {
                        boolean status = path.mkdirs();
                    }
                    File uploadedFile = new File(path + "/" + fileName);
                    // System.out.println(uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    item.write(uploadedFile);
                }
            }
        } catch (FileUploadException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    response.sendRedirect("/EventCalendar-war/pages/user_pages/user_create_event.jsp");
}
```

This is my code.When there is no file to upload I got `java.io.FileNotFoundException` .If file is upload with form data it's work fine.What is wrong with my code?

Comment: How should I handle when there is no upload files?

Comment: Are there anyone know how to solve this problem?